# accessibility when focused link is hidden behind a fixed-position footer when using TAB to proceed

Tags: css, accessibility, wcag, keyboard-navigation

I ran into a detail concerning accessibility, not in regard to screenreaders and blind users, but in regard to pure keyboard navigation.

---

Edit / Addition: I would like to emphasize a part of my question which hasn't been addressed at all in the two answers I got until now: I wonder if the situation given in my snippet can be considered accessible, i.e. would conform to accessibility standards?

---

I have a list of blog posts on a page whose titles are linked to the actual (single) posts - standard blog behaviour. Now, when someone uses the TAB key to navigate and to proceed from one link/blog header to the next, the page will always scroll automatically to show the focused link inside the visible part of the page.

But if I have a fixed footer (same goes for header), at some point the focused link will be hidden by the footer. I am NOT talking about the last few lines on the page! Try the snippet below: Click on one of the visible links to focus it, then use the TAB key to jump to the next, then the next and so on: At some point, the focused link will be behind the footer. Same when I go back (using shift + tab) after the page has already scrolled down: At some point the focused link is behind the fixed header.

Setting a top and bottom padding or margin doesn't help in this case...

I know it is possible to manually scroll down using the arrow keys, but first of all I wonder if this can still be considered fully accessible, and apart from that I simply wonder if there is anything to make the browser scroll the focused element into the visible part of the element it's in?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  padding: 40px 0 80px;
}
li {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  padding: 0 60px;
}

a:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>This is a fixed header</header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 15</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 16</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 17</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 18</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 19</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 20</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 21</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 22</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 23</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 24</a></li>
</ul>
<footer>
  <p>This is a fixed footer<br>The slight transparency of the background color is only used to show what is behind it - on a real website the background would be a non-transparent color.</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simply CSS to solve this. There is a `scroll-margin` property which is also applied when the browser automatically scrolls to the focused element.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  padding: 40px 0 80px;
}
li {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  padding: 0 60px;
}

a:focus {
  scroll-margin: 40px 0 80px; /* header's and footer's height */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>This is a fixed header</header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 15</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 16</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 17</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 18</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 19</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 20</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 21</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 22</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 23</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 24</a></li>
    </ul>
    <footer>
      <p>
        This is a fixed footer<br />The slight transparency of the background
        color is only used to show what is behind it - on a real website the
        background would be a non-transparent color.
      </p>
    </footer>
```

Comment: wow, thank you for that answer! I think that property didn't exist yet when I posted this question almost five years ago, or at least it wasn't widely supported yet – very good to know!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: make **html** smaller ...

```css
html {
height: calc(100% - 120px);
margin-top: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  adding: 40px 0 80px;
}
li {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  padding: 0 60px;
}

a:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>This is a fixed header</header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 15</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 16</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 17</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 18</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 19</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 20</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 21</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 22</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 23</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 24</a></li>
</ul>
<footer>
  <p>This is a fixed footer<br>The slight transparency of the background color is only used to show what is behind it - on a real website the background would be a non-transparent color.</footer>
```

Comment: that's a good idea! I wonder if all browsers will accept that without causing some other trouble, and if animation scripts etc. could still be used in a similar way as without that special setting (for example animating the height of the header when scrolling down would require animating height and top margin of the 'html' element simultaneously).

Answer (score 1):

Since both header and footer are fixed why not using a configuration where the scroll is moved to the content area instead of the whole document:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;
}
li {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  margin-top:auto;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgba(33, 233, 158, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  padding: 0 60px;
}

a:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>This is a fixed header</header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 15</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 16</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 17</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 18</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 19</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 20</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 21</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 22</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 23</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link to blogpost 24</a></li>
</ul>
<footer>
  <p>This is a fixed footer<br>The slight transparency of the background color is only used to show what is behind it - on a real website the background would be a non-transparent color.</footer>
```

Comment: I am aware of that possibility, but first of all, the real situation is more complex (the header is fixed, but among other things its height is animated/getting lower when scrolling down),  second, I am searching for a more general solution (this is a situation that happens often) and third (first part of my question) I am really wondering if the possibility to aditionally scroll using the arrow keys classifies a situation like this as being "officially" accessible. Probably it is, but I am wondering.